# javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD is added automatically to web.xml

Tags: xml, jsf-2

I faced a problem in  `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD<br>`where i found the  `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` is set to client where it made problem with `@ViewScoped`

My question is that, i didn't add this tag i found it added to the
`web.xml` automatically
so in which cases is this tag added and why?

Comment: How did you setup your project? Where does the web.xml come frome? What tools are you using? We need some more information here.

Comment: i am adding a new dynamic web project and in the eclipse wizard i am asking to generate the web.xml
but at generation this tag was not added but after adding managed beans and pages and found the problem with view scoped i found this tag in web.xml and i am sure i didn't add it

Comment: Maybe some plugin that you are using did it, for exmaple the ICEfaces plugin will add it to the web.xml, when you enable it under project facets. Check the history of the file to see exactly when it was added.

Comment: how to check history of file ??
but i am using primeface not ICEFace

Comment: Right click on the file, under Team there should be an entry called 'show local history' (you can also check the history in the version control system if you are using one).